# Need to redirect comand's stdout to another command and stderr to a file

Tags: unix

For example command ls filename. I need that command's result to redirect to a command grep 'rwx' and if there is no such a file in that case redirect stderr to a file.

maybe something like that: ls filename | grep 'rwx' 2> filename2?

Answer (score 2):

I think this might help you with your problem:

```bash
cat not-exists.txt 2>error.log | grep "something"
```

Or if you want to append to the file without overwriting it's content:

```bash
cat not-exists.txt 2>>error.log | grep "something"
```

Note that if the file exists then the content will be searched through by `grep`.

Comment: I can see no difference between the two command lines you posted. Did you accidentally paste the same one twice?

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for the comment. Yea I forgot to put the extra ">" in the second line.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
{ ls -l filename | grep 'rwx'; } 2>error.txt
```

This will save any error message from `ls` *or* `grep`  in `error.txt`, and leave it empty if no error happens.